# Doubt about attributes (getting the brand)

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, eav-attributes

I am a little confused about attributes whether they are simple eav attributes or not.

I dont fully understand **when** an attribute has option or option value. How can i check it?

So, for example in this case i am trying to obtain the **brand name** so i did this query:

```
SELECT main.sku, option_value_ez_catalog_product_brand.value AS ez_catalog_product_brand, code_status.value AS code_status
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute attribute_code_status ON attribute_code_status.attribute_code = 'status' and attribute_code_status.entity_type_id = 4
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute attribute_ez_catalog_product_brand ON attribute_ez_catalog_product_brand.attribute_code = 'ez_catalog_product_brand' and attribute_code_status.entity_type_id = 4

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int code_status ON main.entity_id = code_status.entity_id and code_status.attribute_id = attribute_code_status.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int ez_catalog_product_brand ON main.entity_id = ez_catalog_product_brand.entity_id and ez_catalog_product_brand.attribute_id = attribute_ez_catalog_product_brand.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option option_ez_catalog_product_brand on option_ez_catalog_product_brand.attribute_id = ez_catalog_product_brand.attribute_id and option_ez_catalog_product_brand.option_id = ez_catalog_product_brand.value
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value option_value_ez_catalog_product_brand on option_ez_catalog_product_brand.option_id = option_value_ez_catalog_product_brand.option_id
```

Is that okay? How can i know if an attribute is simple or not?

What about other attributes like : manufacturer, volume, description, prices and so on?

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the type of an EAV attribute from its settings in the `eav_attribute` table:

`backend_type = int` means that the attribute is of type integer and the value is stored in the table `[entity_type_code]_entity_int`, in case of a product attribute from 
`catalog_product_entity_int`. (For other backend types there are corresponding tables, `backend_type = varchar` has `catalog_product_entity_varchar` etc. `backend_type = static` attributes are stored in the entity_table `catalog_product_entity` - e.g. `sku`).

If an integer attribute has `frontend_type = select` that means that some kind of integer key is stored in `[entity_type_code]_entity_int` and there is a related value to that key.
For this type of attributes there is usually a setting in the `source_model` column. Attributes with option values usually have `source_model = eav/entity_attribute_source_table`. Other types of backend models store the data in other tables - where and how exatly the data is stored can be seen in the corresponding Magento class (i.e. in case of `eav/entity_attribute_source_table` `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table`).

Regarding your select:

To get the option values of an product attribute with options you will have to join 4 tables:
`eav_attribute`,`catalog_product_entity_int`,`eav_attribute_option` and`eav_attribute_option_value`
and you will have to do that for every attribute. You may shortcut that by hardcoding the `attribute_id` in your statement and skip the table `eav_attribute`, but the other 3 tables need to be there.

Your statement is correct, you have just a little copy & paste error:
In the second join you use `attribute_code_status.entity_type_id = 4` instead of `attribute_ez_catalog_product_brand.entity_type_id = 4`.

Comment: Excellent!, i told you before but you rock :)

Comment: Hey dude, could you please take a look at this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285837/validate-email-using-magento-1-9-not-way

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285837/validate-email-using-magento-1-9-not-way